# changing persian date "Text" to Real "Date" in Power Bi - Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerapps, persian-calendar

I want to change the perisan Date with text type:

[image: persian calender with Text Format]

to perisan Date with Date type like normal gregorian Dates :

[image: persian calender with Date Format]

but the problem is that Power BI & PowerQuery don't support Persian calendar so I have errors in some records like
[image]

this should be date.

If not, I can't use "between" slicer in my Reports what should I do?

Comment: See [Supported languages and countries/regions for Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/supported-languages-countries-regions). Persian is not supported. So while you can parse/format Persian dates (see answer below), the report and visuals will not display Persian dates and instead use Georgian.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
let  Source =#table({"Jalali_1"},{{"1399/01/01"},{"1399/01/05"}}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Jalali_1", type date}} , "fa-IR")
in #"Changed Type"
```